# How can I debug a Typoscript in Typo3 version 12.4.5.?

Tags: typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-12.x

I had a working Typoscript Layout for my website under Typo3 7.X and after upgrading to Typo3 version 12.4.5 the TS do not work again. Only a white site is beeing displayed. How can I debug the TS code to make it run again in the ver 12.4.5? Is there a HOW-TO where are the differences between ver 7.X and 12.X? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, debugging TypoScript is not easy because there are many influences like the active page and conditions.

I just checked and with the new TypoScript syntax parser in V12 errors and warnings are no more displayed like it used to be with "template analyzer" in previous versions.

But you can copy your TypoScript Setup and Constant to file and use a syntax highlighter in your favorite text editor to show misspellings, example:

- PhpStorm [TypoScript plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11243-typo3-typoscript--enterprise)

You can use the admin panel in the frontend and have a look at section TypoScript, use "TS Tree Settings" to define which information you want to see.

Use TypoScript debug functions:

> TypoScript itself offers a number of debug functions:
>
> . **stdWrap** comes with the properties **debug**, **debugFunc** and **debugData** which help > checking which values are currently available and which configuration is being handled.
>
> . **TMENU** comes with the property **debugItemConf**. If set to 1, it outputs the configuration arrays for each menu item. Useful to debug **optionSplit** things and such.

Have a look at documentation : https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/UsingSetting/Debugging.html

I also suggest you to have a look at breaking changes with the new TypoScript parser :
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/12.0/Breaking-97816-TypoScriptSyntaxChanges.html#breaking-97816-1656350406